# How to setup a Custom Taxonomy Term template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a Custom Post Type and 2 taxonomies attached to it. Each taxonomy has about 20 terms containing several posts. While I have successfully setup a custom archive template for my custom-post-type. My Taxonomy terms are creating problem. When I view any of the terms page (by clicking them from CPT menu) it shows me the titles of the posts under it.

I tried setting up taxonomy-my-taxonomy-my-term.php but the page does not pick it up. Instead it is using archive template. Here is the body class that is returned:

archive tax-path term-a-path term-19 logged-in

Which template do I need to make in order to list all posts under a specific term, and can I have a generic template for all terms, since all of them have posts with similar data fields.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why your `taxonomy-my-taxonomy-my-term.php` is not working... If you want all of the terms of the custom taxonomy to have the same layout use `taxonomy-my-taxonomy.php`. If you want all of your custom taxonomies to be displayed in the same way you could even use `taxonomy.php`.

In case you haven't done yet, check out [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) or [this cool graphic](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

Comment: Hey @alpipego - thanks for the reply. I got the issue sorted out in another thread, and you are right - taxonomy-my-taxonomy.php solved it.